# MassTransit - Publish to a queue consumed by a different worker

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit with RabbitMQ and I have a worker which configures queues and consumers - what I wish to do is be able to give it "roles" telling it what queues it should be able to consume.

My code looks like this:

```
x.UsingRabbitMq((context, config) =>
{
    config.Host(server, virtualHost, h =>
    {
        h.Username(username);
        h.Password(password);
    });

    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.AddConsumer<OrderConsumer>();
        x.AddConsumer<OrderMessagingConsumer>();
        x.AddConsumer<InventoryConsumer>();
    });

    config.ReceiveEndpoint("Orders", cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Durable = true;
        cfg.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 10;
        cfg.PrefetchCount = 40;
        cfg.ConfigureConsumer<OrderConsumer>(context, cfg => {});
    }

    config.ReceiveEndpoint("Orders.Messages", cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Durable = true;
        cfg.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 10;
        cfg.PrefetchCount = 40;
        cfg.ConfigureConsumer<OrderMessagingConsumer>(context, cfg => {});
    }

    config.ReceiveEndpoint("Inventory", cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Durable = true;
        cfg.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 10;
        cfg.PrefetchCount = 40;
        cfg.ConfigureConsumer<InventoryConsumer>(context, cfg => {});
    }
}
```

The code above works as expected, queues are created and messages are consumed. It's important to note that the `OrderConsumer` as part of it's logic creates a message published to `Inventory` which is consumed by `InventoryConsumer`.

To make it conditional by the worker roles I change it to something like this:

```
x.UsingRabbitMq((context, config) =>
{
    config.Host(server, virtualHost, h =>
    {
        h.Username(username);
        h.Password(password);
    });

    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        if (workerRoles.OrderProcessor)
        {
            x.AddConsumer<OrderConsumer>();
            x.AddConsumer<OrderMessagingConsumer>();
        }

        if (workerRoles.InventoryProcessor)
        {
            x.AddConsumer<InventoryConsumer>();
        }
    });

    if (workerRoles.OrderProcessor)
    {
        config.ReceiveEndpoint("Orders", cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Durable = true;
            cfg.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 10;
            cfg.PrefetchCount = 40;
            cfg.ConfigureConsumer<OrderConsumer>(context, cfg => {});
        }

        config.ReceiveEndpoint("Orders.Messages", cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Durable = true;
            cfg.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 10;
            cfg.PrefetchCount = 40;
            cfg.ConfigureConsumer<OrderMessagingConsumer>(context, cfg => {});
        }
    }

    if (workerRoles.InventoryProcessor)
    {
        config.ReceiveEndpoint("Inventory", cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Durable = true;
            cfg.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 10;
            cfg.PrefetchCount = 40;
            cfg.ConfigureConsumer<InventoryConsumer>(context, cfg => {});
        }
    }
}
```

When I add the conditionals then the `Inventory` queue is not created and therefor messages published by `OrderConsumer` are not queued and therefor are not handled (by another worker that has the `InventoryProcessor` flag turned on).

I tried changing the logic that the code is exactly as in first example but the queue has a `ConcurrentMessageLimit` and a `PrefetchCount` be equal to 0 - but this just queues the messages and immidiatly moves them to a `Inventory_skipped` queue.

What I wish to accomplish/understand is how do I handle a situation where a worker should publish to a queue not consumed by that worker. Should all my workers in such case define all queues that all other workers are working with? (imagine a situation where a worker is not defining the queue and start working but the worker that defines the queue is not yet up and running to create it).

Answer (score 0):

There are some aspects of your configuration that are of massive concern, particularly calling `AddMassTransit` inside the bus configuration? Very odd. I've updated your configuration as requested to use what I'd consider a manageable solution:

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
   if (workerRoles.OrderProcessor)
   {
        x.AddConsumer<OrderConsumer>()
            .Endpoint(e => e.Name = "Orders");
        x.AddConsumer<OrderMessagingConsumer>()
            .Endpoint(e => e.Name = "Orders.Messages");   
   }

    if (workerRoles.InventoryProcessor)
    {
        x.AddConsumer<InventoryConsumer>()
            .Endpoint(e => e.Name = "Inventory");    
    }

    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, config) =>
    {
        config.Host(server, virtualHost, h =>
        {
            h.Username(username);
            h.Password(password);
        });

        config.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 10;
        config.PrefetchCount = 40;

        config.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The thing is to move the name of the queue to the consumer outside the `UsingRabbitMQ`? Will it solve the issue I'm trying to solve above?

Comment: Well, calling `AddMassTransit` inside the `UsingRabbitMq` won't work at all because the service collection would be modified after the service provider has already been created.

Comment: But this is not the case. I'm calling `UsingRabbitMq` inside `AddMassTransit`.

Comment: Then update your question to reflect that, because it's clearly not aligning with what you just stated. Anyway, my answer stands. Good luck.

Comment: In your example above, if `InventoryProcessor` is turned off (meaning queue is not created) how would `OrderConsumer` publish to it?

Comment: If there are no consumers for that message type, resulting in no queue for that message type, then publishing it does nothing. Presumably you have some other service with that consumer creating that queue.

Comment: So a queue would only be created if an explicit service creates an consumes it, otherwise messages published to it are "lost"? In that case what if service A which creates some Q-A  is down but service B which create Q-B is up then basically the work of service B is redundant if service A is not started before service B?

Comment: That's how publish works, the producer doesn't know/care about the consumers. If you need to guarantee delivery to a single consumer (queue), use Send with a send address of the queue name (`queue:Orders`, or whatever).